# Reading From Shared Memory Using mmap - Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, posix, shared-memory

I'm still trying to wrap my head around shared memory. What I'm trying to accomplish is to have an array of pods. Each pod will also contain an array of keyValue.

```
typedef struct {
   char key[256];
   char value[256];
}keyValue;

typedef struct {
   keyValue **arr;
   int count;
}pod;

int fd;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   int kv_store_create(char *name) {
       return shm_open(name, O_CREAT|O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);
   }

   void kv_store_write(char *key1, char *value1) {

      static pod (*str)[28];

      ftruncate(fd, sizeof(str));

      str = (pod(*)[28])mmap(NULL, sizeof(str), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

      for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
         str[i]->arr = (keyValue **)malloc(28 * sizeof(keyValue));
         for(int j = 0; j < 28; j++) {
            str[i]->arr[j] = (keyValue *)malloc(256 * sizeof(keyValue));
         }
       }

       strncpy(str[0]->arr[0]->key, key1, strlen(key1));
       strncpy(str[0]->arr[0]->value, value1, strlen(value1));
       str[0]->count = 1;
    }

   fd = kv_store_create("sharedmem");

   kv_store_write("key", "value");
```

So at this point, I have a keyValue in a pod, and if I read the shared memory from the same file, I have no issues.

The issue arises when I try to read from another process. I have the following file

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    typedef struct {
        char key[256];
        char value[256];
    }keyValue;

    typedef struct {
        keyValue **arr;
        int count;
    }pod;


    int fd = shm_open("sharedmem", O_RDWR, 0);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("Error... opening shm\n");
    }

    struct stat s;

    if (fstat(fd, &s) == -1) {
        printf("Error fstat\n");
    }

    pod (*str2)[28];

    str2 = (pod(*)[28])mmap(NULL, s.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    printf("%s", str2[0]->arr[0]->key); 

}
```

The printf is causing a seg fault and I believe it is trying to access part of a memory that has nothing allocated, while that printf would actually print in my first file.

I'm trying to figure out why is spitting out an error and what route should I take to be able to share an array of structs between two processes

Thanks!

Comment: [not the cause] `strncpy(str[0]->arr[0]->key, key1, strlen(key1));` is *completely* wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you say is:

> Each pod will also contain an array of keyValue.

But that's not the case, because a pod is:

```
typedef struct {
   keyValue **arr;
   int count;
}pod;
```

which doesn't contain an array of `KeyValue`. It contains a pointer to an array of `KeyValue*`, but the `KeyValue` objects themselves are neither in the `pod` nor in the memory pointed to by `arr`. So they definitely are not in the memory you are sharing between the two processes.

So the reading process gets a`pod` which contains a pointer to an address *in the owning process*; obviously, that pointer is completely meaningless in the reader since processes do not share memory so having an address of an object in another process is more or less equivalent to having a random number.

In short, you have to make sure the shared memory region actually contains all of the objects you want to share, not just pointers to them. And since it is unlikely that `mmap` will return the same address in the two processes, it will not be useful to insert pointers in the shared memory even to objects which are placed in the shared memory.

Comment: Awesome, I've played around a little and managed to share an array of pods that individually contain only a single keyValue with another process by having 
typedef struct { keyValue arr; }.

I'd assume I'd need typedef struct { keyValue *arr; } for an array of keyValue, is that right?

Comment: @Bibik: An array of `KeyValue` is a `KeyValue[]`; it *decays* to a `KeyValue*`, but you should not confuse the two. Also, if you typedef a pointer type, you will almost certainly end up confusing yourself and anyone reading your code. `*`s are pointy and pointy things should be visible; otherwise you end up pricking yourself. What gets complicated is trying to create a dynamically sized array object, because C arrays are always fixed size (even if they are VLAs). In that case, you will need a `KeyValue*`, but try to remember that it is not the same thing as an array.

Comment: @Bibik: by the way, what is the meaning of `count`? And do you really intend the shared data structure to be an array of 28 arrays of 28 `KeyValue`s, for a total of 784 pairs?

Comment: I assume that i'll need the the total count of objects in each keyValue array further down my work. Regarding the number 28, it's just a placeholder but I just changed to 256. I'm looking to write a small program that adds key value pairs in either of the 256 pods using a hash function to make searching a little more efficient. Each pod will also have a limit of 256 key value pairs before forcing some out using the "first in first out" method. btw, I managed to solve my problem that I spent the whole day trying to solve thanks to your help. Thank you very much!

Comment: @BibikA: No worries. (But you could always accept the answer, if it was what you needed :) ). 256 arrays each with 256 pairs each with two 256-byte strings is a total of 32 megabytes. I suppose that's not awful, but it makes non-optimal use of the computer's caches; at some point, you might want to consider compressing the data structures.